# java script, asp.net dropDownList simulate click cross browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im trying to slideUp the elements of a dropDownList when clicking certain span, but afher trying many things, it apears to be not working...
here is what im trying:

```
ddSpan.addEventListener("click",
        function () {
            var ddControl = document.getElementById("<%=ddControl.ClientID %>");
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            var canceled = !ddControl.dispatchEvent(e);
            if (canceled) {
                alert("canceled");
            } else{
                alert("worked");
            }
            $(ddControl).click();
        }, false);
```

I get a "worked" message every time i click on the span, but the dropDown doesn't slide-up.
I also tried with "click" event and `$(ddControl).trigger("click");`

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: do you mean ,you want to expand the select box

Comment: @ Arun P Johny  yes and yes, i can use JQuery, and im trying to expand the select box.

Comment: I was testing the above code mainly in latest version of Firefox without luck.